# Can Dart conditional imports use names?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-android

Consider a conditional import statement. The following comes from the Dart language guide:

```dart
import 'src/hw_none.dart'
    if (dart.library.io) 'src/hw_io.dart'
    if (dart.library.html) 'src/hw_html.dart';
```

Is there a syntax to add a name to these imports? For example, I'd like to say something like the following:

```dart
import 'src/hw_none.dart' as my_prefix
    if (dart.library.io) 'src/hw_io.dart' as my_prefix
    if (dart.library.html) 'src/hw_html.dart' as my_prefix;
```

Unfortunately, the above doesn't compile. I haven't been able to find a variation that does compile.

Is there a way to name conditionally imported packages?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this a few month ago, to implement mobile and web functionalities. Seems like you cannot name each import separately.

```dart
import 'package:flutter_fcm_web_example/notification_helper.dart';
import 'firebase_mobile_messaging.dart'
    if (dart.library.html) 'firebase_web_messaging.dart' as notifInstance;

abstract class NotificationEncapsulation {
  static NotificationHelper get instance =>
      notifInstance.FirebaseMessagingHelper();
}
```

Comment: "dart.library.js" is not a valid conditional import.  Only two: dart.library.io, and dart.library.html.

Comment: Edited my answer with the html library, thanks for the remark.